# What happens if you return a function recursively and is this good practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've written this small random number guessing game as part of my study about Python. My question is, what happens if I return a function by itself? Is this considered good practice? Does this cause some sort of buffer or stack overflow? (no pun intended)

I really haven't found a clear answer, not even for other languages.

If anyone wants to ask why, I did this because I wanted to loop the program until the user types 'exit'.

```
# Simple guess the random number game

# Import this module for generating a random number
import random 

# Function to determine if answer is too low, too high, or if it is correct
def guessFunc(guessInput, randomNum):
    if guessInput < randomNum:
        return 'The number is too low'
    elif guessInput > randomNum:
        return 'The number is too high.'
    else:
        return 'Correct!'

# Function that checks if user input is valid.
def checkValid_Input(userInput):
    if userInput.isdigit():
        return True

    return False

# The "main" function of the whole game
def mainFunc():
    userGuess = ''
    guessResult = ''
    secretNum = random.randint(0, 20) #Generate random number
    tries = 0

    # Game loop, the program ends if user types 'Exit'/'exit'.
    while True:
        print('I\'m thinking of a number between 0 and 20...')
        userGuess = input()

        # Check first if user typed 'exit'. If true, terminates the program
        # if False, continues code execution.
        if str.lower(userGuess) == 'exit':
            return

        # If the previous condition is false, perform this method.
        # This checks if user input is valid.
        isValid = checkValid_Input(userGuess)

        if isValid == False:
            print('Invalid input, please try again.\n')
        else:
            guessResult = guessFunc(int(userGuess), secretNum)
            tries = tries + 1
            print(guessResult + '\n')

            if tries == 6 and guessResult != 'Correct!':
                print('Nope, the secret number is: ' + str(secretNum))
                print('Press any key to continue')
                _ = input()
                return mainFunc()

            if tries <=6 and guessResult == 'Correct!':
                print('It took you ' + str(tries) + ' tries to get it.')
                print('Press any key to continue')
                _ = input()
                return mainFunc()

# Initialize/call main function       
mainFunc()
```

Comment: This is called recursion, it is has many use cases. The default recursion limit in python is 1000, so it likely won't be an issue.

Comment: That is not returning function itself. It's just recursive call and return result. Returning itself means `return mainFunc`.

Comment: Returning the function itself would be unusual. However, here you are talking about a function recursively calling itself. This is a common strategy, however, in python usually you would just use a while loop here. CPython has a pretty strict recursion limit, and because it doesn't support tail call optimization, so too deep a call stack *will cause a stack overflow*

Comment: Ah, so my understanding about recursion is wrong. I thought it's not recursion if there was a return statement preceding a function call. Thank you for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clear things up a little, I stripped this problem down to the bare minimum needed to get some output and traceback.  I placed the code in `test1.py`.

Note that nothing within `mainFunc()` causes even a gradual change leading towards an eventual exit condition so all it does is increment a counter and print the new value before reaching the return statement:

```
count = 0
def mainFunc():
    global count
    count += 1
    print('count:',count)
    return mainFunc()

mainFunc()
```

This caused Python to execute 1012 print statements producing the following (highly abbreviated) output:

```
count: 1
count: 2
...
count: 1012
```

...at which point it failed with the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MyPython\Code\test1.py", line 9, in <module>
    mainFunc()
  File "C:\MyPython\Code\test1.py", line 6, in mainFunc
    return mainFunc()
  File "C:\MyPython\Code\test1.py", line 6, in mainFunc
    return mainFunc()
  File "C:\MyPython\Code\test1.py", line 6, in mainFunc
    return mainFunc()
  [Previous line repeated 1009 more times]
  File "C:\MyPython\Code\test1.py", line 5, in mainFunc
    print('count:',count)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

This makes sense because each time the `return mainFunc()` statement was reached, it invoked `mainFunc()` in order to determine what value to return to the caller (which was implicitly `__main()__` the very first call, and `mainFunc()` itself recursively thereafter).

The Traceback supports our general consensus that it is indeed recursion, and that recursion does have a (default) limit.

Finally, to answer the question `is this good practice?`:

Sometimes yes and sometimes no - I can think of a VERY common application suited to recursive design:

Factorials, where `factorial(n)` should return the output of the calculation of 3 x 2 x 1 = `6`, where `n=3`.  The exit condition would be that each subsequent call invokes factorial(n-1) so the parameter passed progressively decrements towards an exit condition within the function.

In order to recurse there must be an exit condition or the endless loop will eventually cause a `RecursionError`.